# Positioning the floating div

Tags: javascript, html

How do I center a floating div using top and left attributes. This div opens on clicking an image. I cannot use align because I am using a scroll down bar. The div should be centered even when I scroll down. If I use screen width and screen height it stays fixed on the page. There are many queries in this regard but none is using top and left attributes. Javascript is used to set the top and left attributes of this div.

Comment: Center a floated div? Can't think of how that would work, floating is either to the left or right. Posting an example will help others understand what you need

Answer (score 0):

Not sure you can do that with floating div , but, change the floating div to fixed position as soon as you start scrolling by appending class on start of scroll function, when the window top = 0 remove the fixed class and append your floating class....
hope this helps..

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible to post a sample of the page? Can't you just make the div "position:fixed" and then set "left" and "top" as percentages to center the box?  Something like:

```
.popupFixed
{
width:400px; 
left:50%;
margin-left:-200px; //<-- Half container width
top:44%; 
position:fixed;
}
```